# Pass an anonymous function to onPanResponderMove

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a javascript issue and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

In my React Native application, I have a panResponder and I'm using this hook to call Animated.event.

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    /* ... some other methods ... */
    onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, { dx: this.state.x, dy: this.state.y }]),
});
```

Although, I would like the hook to be an anonymous function instead, to be able to do some other things. I tried a few different way to use an anonymous function instead but I can't make it to work.

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    /* ... some other methods ... */
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        this.callSomething(); 
        return Animated.event([null, { /* I'm not sure what to pass here to map with gestureState... */ }]);
    },
});
```

I've read the documentation but even with that I still don't know.

Can you help me out?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I've finally did something like that:

```
let valueY;
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    /* ... some other methods ... */
    onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        valueY = this.state.y._value;
    },
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        this.callSomething();
        let panY = valueY + gestureState.dy;
        this.state.y.setValue({ y: panY });
    },
});
```

I don't think that's the best way to do it though...

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  The syntax in the 2nd version looks fine. Is there an actual error? Is the function not being called? "can't make it work" is too vague.

Comment: The syntax just don't work without any error, when I try to move it just doesn't move anymore

Answer (score 55):

The thing is that **Animated.event(...)** is actually returning a function so to immediately invoke it you have to do something like this:

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  ...
  onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
    // custom logic here
    ...

    Animated.event([null, {
      dx: this.state.pan.x,
      dy: this.state.pan.y,
    }])(e, gestureState); // <<--- INVOKING HERE!
  },
});
```

Comment: Genius! I wish I understood the underlying functionality as well as you do. Works great.

Comment: great! its so useful for me

Answer (score 9):

In case this is useful to anyone, I've just had the same issue. I ended up with, roughly:

```
let mover = Animated.event([ null, { dy: this.state.pan.y }]) ;
let repsponder = PanResponder.create({
    ....
    onPanResponderMove: (e, gesture) => {
        this.doSomething() ;
        return mover(e, gesture) ;
        },
    }) ;
```

The important bit seems to be calling *Animated.event* outside the *onPanResponderMove* code. Note that in the examples that usually appear, the code is *onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(...)* so a single *Animated.event* thing gets created, but if you it inside the *onPanResponderMove* code (as in alexmngn's first attempt), a new thing (whatever it is!) gets created on every call of the *onPanResponderMove* code - which I'm guessing is the problem.

Comment: Yes sir, this scratched my head on this one for a while on this one. Thank you.